# Unable to PUSH after COMMIT with git GUI

Tags: git, bash, visual-studio, version-control

I want to use a dropbox folder to store a GIT origin repo (Visual Studio solution). So I've used git GUI to create a new repo in my folder, then I've moved my project sources in it and clone this repo on two machines, in Visual Studio Project folder. I'm able to commit changes from VS and GIT bash/GUI but I'm not able to push these change into the origin in dropbox, this is the error from git GUI:

```
Pushing to C:/Users/noomak/Dropbox/git/repo/project1
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master        
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository        
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent        
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match        
remote: the work tree to HEAD.        
remote: 
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable        
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into        
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you        
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some        
remote: other way.        
remote: 
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set        
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.        
To C:/Users/noomak/Dropbox/git/repo/project1
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'C:/Users/noomak/Dropbox/git/repo/project1'`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you should normally not push to a non-bare repository and without extra actions you also cannot push into the currently checked out branch. You should make your "remote" repository be a bare repository by using `--bare` on `git init`.

Comment: after 'git init --bare' I'm not able anymore to add manually the project and see the update in GIT, the structure from this command and 'create new repo' through the GUI is significantly different

Comment: understood how to do work with that; with a bare repo, it is needed to fill it from outside project and it works

Comment: Your "central" repo should be the bare one. Your local repos where you do the work should be non-bare clones of teh central bare one.